# How to know Client Access Server FQDN from Client Access Server hostname

Tags: c++, active-directory, exchange-server, mapi

I have follow this instructions https://exchangeserverpro.com/exchange-server-2010-cas-array to setup Exchange Servers.

Currently I have a CAS server:SerCAS, and it fqdn is outlook-cas.domain.local.

And I trying to create outlook profile by using MAPI, I am using the CAS server hostname:SerCAS but the function ConfigureMsgService failed. So I try the fqdn name:outlook-cas.domain.local, and it works.

Is that a way to query the fqdn from the hostname?

Answer (score 0):

You need to retrieve autodiscover XML. You can test it in Outlook: Ctrl+right click on the Outlook tray icon and select "Test Email Autoconfiguration".